# Can I retrieve Historical weather forecast from IBM API

Tags: ibm-cloud, weather-api

I wonder if I can retrieve historical weather forecast from the IBM weather company API.
I am particularly interested in comparing what the weather company had forecasted for the past two years compared to the actual weather over the same period.

Looking at the documentation it doesn't seem to be possible to retrieve forecast data for past date, but that sounds weird to me.

Answer (score 1):

After talking with the Weather Company Data service team within IBM, I have confirmation that, unfortunately, historical weather forecasts are not available on IBM Bluemix. If that is something that you would find valuable, we welcome your structured ideas, which you can submit here: https://ibmcloud.ideas.aha.io/

Answer (score 0):

may be an explanation : the terms and conditions said that almanac data could be retreive for US country only.
https://www-03.ibm.com/software/sla/sladb.nsf/pdf/7148-03/$file/i126-7148-03_07-2016_en_US.pdf